# How can I disable the events of all the layout when timer is running?

Tags: android, layout, timer

I have a timer that's running. It starts and stops when the textview is clicked. What I want to do is make it so that when it is running, I click anywhere on the layout/screen to stop the timer. However, I also don't want it to click anything under it. Say, I click a button, I don't want it to also click that button. Just stop the timer.

Unfortunately, I can't seem to get the last part going. Any clue? Here's what I have:

```
  //set on Click listener for whole layout:
    RelativeLayout bSheetLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.bout_sheet);
    bSheetLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //if timer is running, stop timer

            if (bTimerRunning) {

                TextView etTimer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTimer);

                //perform timer click
                //will pause timer 
                etTimer.performClick();

                return;

            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Well of course the most straightforward way is to do condition check `if (bTimerRunning)` in other click listeners.

Or you can create a custom view. Extend any View class and add these

```
MyClickListener listener;

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    listener.onClick();
    return true; 
}

public interface MyClickListener{
    public void onClick(); 
}
```

The point is this view will consume touch event and when it does trigger the `onClick` listener which you can use to stop your timer. 
Add this view to the top of all other views filling the screen and set the background color to transparent. When your timer is running, set the visibility to visible and gone when it's not.